# WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, swift, sockets, wkwebview

I am trying to have a survey where the buttons are manually clicked through .evaluteJavaScript. The Javascript functions are called whenever an incoming message is received (I shortened it a little). Basically everything works except evaluating the Javascript:

If I run this exact Javascript in Webview:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    setupButtonScripts(webView: webView)
}
```

it works perfectly, so I don't think its an issue with Javascript syntax or anything. The print statement at the end runs. Why could this be happening?

```swift
init(_ parent: WebViewWrapper) {
    self.parent = parent
    self.webView = WKWebView() // Initialize the webView property
    self.messageHandler = MessageHandler(address: my ipad, port: ___)
    super.init()
    messageHandler.messageReceivedHandler = { [weak self] message in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.handleButtonActionForMessage(message, webView: self?.webView ?? WKWebView())
        }
    }
}

func handleButtonActionForMessage(_ message: String, webView: WKWebView) {
    case "one":
        let script = """
        var answer1 = document.getElementById("ANSWER_1");
        if (answer1) {
            answer1.click();
        }
        """

        webView.evaluateJavaScript(script, completionHandler: nil)
        print("ran this function")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **evaluateJavaScript** function works asynchronously. Ensure that the JavaScript code is being evaluated after the web page has fully loaded. In your code, you're calling evaluateJavaScript immediately after constructing the JavaScript string. Make sure you're calling it after the WebView has finished loading the web content.

Comment: The nature of the flow of the code (which isn't in the code I included, sorry!) is such that the webpage itself will be loaded whenever the function is being called, as it is in response to a message sent by extracted text from the same webpage, if that makes sense. Would this still be an applicable issue then?